# Unable to checkout git directory

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a git subdirectory

https://github.com/graphlab-code/graphlab/src ... I am trying to checkout only `src` subdirectory

```
mkdir git-src
cd git-src
git init
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo graphlab/src/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add origin https://github.com/graphlab-code/graphlab
git pull origin master
```

The above code doesnt seem to copy the subdirectory `src`. kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put only the local path `src`, not the '`repo/src`' ('`graphlab/src`') in the `sparse-checkout` file.

```
echo src/*> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

That is because [`git read-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) reads local path from within the repo, defined in  the skip-worktree bitmap `$GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout`.

I managed to copy src only with the `src/*` syntax.

All other attempts left me with:

```
error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory
```

Comment: echo src/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout.. i have changed to this... still not copying "src" folder...

Comment: @user3411047 ok, I have edited my answer, and tested the solution: src is now copied